# queryParams link does not refresh when clicking on another link which pointing to the same component

Tags: html, angular, angular-routing

here is my html the points to the component (just one of the options) -

```
<a
  class="linkCategoriesInner__link"
  [routerLink]="['/product-list']"
  [queryParams]="{ gender: 2, category: 5 }">
  Sneakers
</a>
```

here is my component ngOnInit -

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe((data: Data) => {
      const products = data['users'] as IProductInterface[];
      this._products = products.map((product) => new Product(product));
    })
  }
```

when im clicking on another option it does not refresh the page, how can i change that. thx

Answer (score 0):

Angular is not useful for refreshing the same page/ any page, since it is for SPAs. You might want to try programmatically refreshing the page.

Also if you intent to refresh data rather than refreshing page, you might want to check the docs on that.

Answer (score 0):

- Angular is not useful for refreshing the same page. you might want to
  try programmatically refreshing the page.

---

Bind a click event to your `anchor` tag. when you click the `anchor` tag, it's called the method to refresh your page.

```
    <a
      click="refreshPage()"
      class="linkCategoriesInner__link"
      [routerLink]="['/product-list']"
      [queryParams]="{ gender: 2, category: 5 }">
      Sneakers
    </a>

    constructor(private router: Router){
       this.refreshPage();
    }

    refreshPage():any{
     this.route.data.subscribe((data: Data) => {
          const products = data['users'] as IProductInterface[];
          this._products = products.map((product) => new Product(product));
        })
    }
```